# why does excel shift numbers when trying to perform percentages?

Tags: excel

I have a table 100 rows strong.  on the A column I have a value.  on the B Column, I have a count.  The data starts on row 2.

At the bottom of the B column I have a sum total.

I need to create a C Column of percentages.

Right now if I put in C2 `=B2/B101`  I get the answer I'm looking for.

At the bottom right of the cell is that little box to expand the query...

my problem is when that happens, I'm looking for:

```
C2=>`=B2/B101`
C3=>`=B3/B101`
C4=>`=B4/B101`,
```

but the autopopulate ends up with:

```
C2 => `=B2/B101`
C3 => `=B3/B102`  <-- Should be 101
C4 => `=B4/B103`  <-- Should be 101
```

how do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then make that row Absolute with `$`:

```
=B2/B$101
```

Now it will not change

Comment: You sir, are a scholar!  This was killing me.  it's always the simple things.  Thanks!